# what is the result of 4*0:g_range[2]?

Tags: r

i have got  pieces of code:

```
cars <- c(1, 3, 6, 4, 9)
trucks <- c(2, 5, 4, 5, 12)
g_range <- range(0, cars, trucks)
axis(2, las=1, at=4*0:g_range[2])
```

there is a comment:Make y axis with horizontal labels that display ticks at every 4 marks.
4*0:g_range[2] is equivalent to c(0,4,8,12).

i run:

```
> 4*0:g_range[2]
[1]  0  4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48
```

4*0:g_range[2] is equivalent to c(0,4,8,12).?
4*0:g_range[2]=c(0,4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48)   not  c(0,4,8,12)

Comment: Can you please change the title of your question so that it is meaningful for anybody else trying to search for something similar?

Comment: Also, what exactly are you asking? You input some code. R gives the answer. Your desired answer of `c(0, 4, 8, 12)` is clearly not the result of the code you wrote.  There is no question here, so unless you modify and clean up your question, I shall vote to close.

Comment: @Fnzh Xx you did clean up the title but it's still not ver informative.  Think more generic.  Ask yourself what terms might a future searcher use to find my question.  As it stands the question is very narrow and only useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0:n` returns the vector `c(0, 1, 2, ..., n)` and `4*0:n` will multiply each element by 4 to yield `c(0, 4, 8, ..., 4n)`. So, this gives a vector in which the *difference* between each element is 4. It does *not* give a vector of four equally spaced elements except in the case that `n` is 3.